# How to get XPath query in response from SOAPUI

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy, soapui, cdata

I would like write a xPath query for SOAPUI for the validation of parameter Score only under "BDS" for validation value in the parameter.

All response from the code is here:

```html
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <MatchResponse xmlns="http://www.bottomline.com/intellinx/webservices">
         <MatchResult><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ResultBlock>
<MatchSummary matches="1">
<TotalMatchScore>50</TotalMatchScore>
<Rules totalRuleCount="5">
<Rule ruleCount="1">
<RuleID>Rule3_2_R</RuleID>
<Score>10</Score>
</Rule>
<Rule ruleCount="1">
<RuleID>Rule18_In</RuleID>
<Score>20</Score>
</Rule>
<Rule ruleCount="1">
<RuleID>Rule14_Su</RuleID>
<Score>20</Score>
</Rule>
</Rules>
</MatchSummary>
<ExternalScores>
<ExternalScore>
<extClientLegacy>2003-01-03-03.26.32.285776</extClientLegacy>
<SourceID>BDS</SourceID>
<Score>-1.0</Score>
</ExternalScore>
<ExternalScore>
<extClientLegacy>2003-01-03-03.26.32.285776</extClientLegacy>
<SourceID>O2</SourceID>
<Score>0.128</Score>
</ExternalScore>
</ExternalScores>
<ErrorWarnings>
<Errors errorCount="0"/>
<Warnings warningCount="0"/>
</ErrorWarnings>
</ResultBlock>]]></MatchResult>
      </MatchResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

SOAPUI is on the image. And the question is how can i write the xpath.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? Do you want to check the `Score` as `-1` when `ScoreID` is `BSD`?

Comment: Pavel, The data posted is not parsable.

Comment: Please don't post "write code for me" questions. If you have problems with a certain XPath expression, include that expression and some reasoning about it. If you have no XPath expression so far, spend some more time to think about your problem and come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is inside of `cdata`, you may have to use `groovy` to achieve the same.

**Note**  that the your xml response is **edited to make it parse** correctly. You may not face this problem as you will have a actual response.

In short, here is what needs to be done:
 - extract `cdata` part first to get actual xml where you need to apply the xpath
 - then extract `xpath`

Here is the `Groovy Script`

```
def xml = """<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <MatchResponse xmlns="http://www.bottomline.com/intellinx/webservices">
         <MatchResult><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ResultBlock>
<MatchSummary matches="1">
<TotalMatchScore>50</TotalMatchScore>
<Rules totalRuleCount="5">
<Rule ruleCount="1">
<RuleID>Rule3_2_R</RuleID>
<Score>10</Score>
</Rule>
<Rule ruleCount="1">
<RuleID>Rule18_In</RuleID>
<Score>20</Score>
</Rule>
<Rule ruleCount="1">
<RuleID>Rule14_Su</RuleID>
<Score>20</Score>
</Rule>
</Rules>
</MatchSummary>
<ExternalScores>
<ExternalScore>
<extClientLegacy>2003-01-03-03.26.32.285776</extClientLegacy>
<SourceID>BDS</SourceID>
<Score>-1.0</Score>
</ExternalScore>
<ExternalScore>
<extClientLegacy>2003-01-03-03.26.32.285776</extClientLegacy>
<SourceID>O2</SourceID>
<Score>0.128</Score>
</ExternalScore>
</ExternalScores>
<ErrorWarnings/>
<Errors errorCount="0"/>
</ResultBlock>]]>
</MatchResult>
</MatchResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>"""

//The data you are looking for
//You may edit as you needed

def lookForScoreID = 'BDS'
def expectedScore = '-1.0'

//Closure to extract data of given node name
def searchData = { data, element ->
   def parsedData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
   parsedData.'**'.find {it.name() == element} as String
}

//Closure to check the xpath
def searchByXpath = {data, xpath ->
   def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(data)
   holder.getNodeValue(xpath)
}

//Gets the CDATA part of the response
//NOTE: if you want to use Script Assertion, use **context.response** instead of **xml** in the below statement. Also, you can remove the above xml.

def cdata = searchData(xml, 'MatchResult')
println cdata
def actualScore = searchByXpath(cdata, "//ExternalScore[SourceID = '$lookForScoreID']/Score")
log.info actualScore
assert expectedScore == actualScore, "Score is not matching for SourceID ${lookForScoreID}"
```

You can also use the above script as `Script Assertion` instead of a separate `groovy script` test step, please see the note in the comment part i.e., use **context.response** instead of **xml**

Having said that, you do not required `xpath` assertion.